# WPF The ControlTemplate I use for the Validation.ErrorTemplate cannot access the parent Control

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I am trying to set the margin of my custom ComboBox when it has a Validation Error.
Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
<ComboBox x:Class="Emsc.Prestige.Windows.AutoCompleteComboBox"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          x:Name="MyComboBox">

    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border x:Name="ErrorBorder" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                <AdornerElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
            </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=adorner, Converter={StaticResource ErrorContentToErrorTypeConverter}}"
                                                        Value="Critical">
                <Setter TargetName="ErrorBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                <Setter TargetName="MyComboBox" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

So when I set the BorderBrush for the ErrorBorder element, it works fine. But when I try to access the Margin property (or any property) of my MyComboBox, I get the following error:

> The property 'TargetName' does not represent a valid target for the
>   'Setter' because an element named 'MyComboBox' was not found. Make
>   sure that the target is declared before any Setters, Triggers or
>   Conditions that use it.

I would like to access the Margin of MyComboBox in XAML and not in code behind.
Is there a way to access the "TemplatedParent" through the Setter in my DataTrigger?

Answer (score 0):

try to use style element, something like this

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

apply this style to your combobox